# Dúvidas com banco de dados e login

Tags: java, sql, query

eu comecei recentemente a programar em Java e acabei tendo o seguinte erro com o método "validaLogin".

> "Não foi possível conectar com o banco de dados: o Índice da coluna
> está fora do intervalo:2, numero de coluns: 1".

Procurei por todo canto mas não achei nada que solucionasse esse problema, refiz o método de outras formas mas nada de resolver.

Segue meu método:

```
private final String LISTBYID = "SELECT email, senha FROM pessoa WHERE id = ?";

    public void validaLogin(String txEmail, String senha) {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = FabricaConexao.getConexao();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(LISTBYID);
            stmt.setString(1, txEmail);
            stmt.setString(2, senha);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(rs + "\n" + stmt);

            while (rs.next()) {
                
                if(txEmail == rs.getString("email") && senha == rs.getString("senha")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bem vindo " + rs.getString("nome") +" !");
                    TabelaPessoaExame pagIni = new TabelaPessoaExame();
                    pagIni.setVisible(true);
                    pagIni.dispose();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Não foi possível conectar " + "com o banco de dados! " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

//-----------------------
//Btn da página de login onde chamo meu método

```
JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    PessoaDao dao = new PessoaDao();
    String valor = new String(passSenha.getPassword());
    dao.validaLogin(TxEmail.getText(), valor);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua query tem apenas um parâmetro a ser adicionado, o id:

```
private final String LISTBYID = "SELECT email, senha FROM pessoa WHERE id = ?";
```

e você está tentando encaixar 2 parâmetros:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(LISTBYID);
stmt.setString(1, txEmail);
stmt.setString(2, senha);
```

Por isso o erro dizendo que está fora do intervalo.

A sua query está buscando os campos email e senha (select email, senha), da tabela pessoa (from pessoa) onde o id é igual a um parâmetro que você deve passar (where id = ?).

Acredito que não era essa sua intenção, uma sugestão é buscar pelo login, e então comparar a senha. Buscar por login e senha, e depois comparar os dois campos vai ser sempre true, já que você buscou por eles. Buscar por ID não parece fazer sentido, já que o usuário não informa o ID dele, apenas o email e senha.